# How to find the last two digits of the integer part of $a_{n}=(2+\sqrt{3})^{2^{n}}$ when n=2020?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the last two digits of the integer part of $a_{n}=(2+\sqrt{3})^{2^{n}}$ when n=2020.
I can find a $b_{n}=(2+\sqrt{3})^{2^{n}}+(2-\sqrt{3})^{2^{n}}$
so $b_{n+1}=b_{n}^2-2$ and interger part of $a_{n}=b_{n}-1$;But I don't know how to find the last two digits of the integer part of $a_{2020}$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Consider to edit the question with your attempt to solve the problem, otherwise it will probably be closed as it's a requirement on this site to show what one has attempted before asking for help

Comment: Please provide context to the question. This includes the own effort in a relevant manner. You may also include the source, the level, author, where did it appear, etc. - see also the guidelines of providing relevant context to support the question as in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question . If not doing so, the question will attract many downvotes - and will be open to votes to be closed for the mentioned reason of a missing context.

Comment: A general hint for textbook exercises.  Look at the material just before this in the book.

Comment: Can you estimate $a_n-b_n$? What can you say about $b_n$?

Comment: $x \mapsto {\rm mod}(x^2-2,100)$ is a map from a finite set to itself. If you start from $x = b_0 = 4$, repeat iterate the map to generate ${\rm mod}(b_n,100)$, sooner or later the sequence of last two digits of $b_n$ will become periodic....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't know how to find the last two digits

You are almost there... With your definition you get a recursive sequence
$$b_{n+1} = b_n^2-2\ ,\quad b_0=4$$
As you are only interested in the lowest two digits, it's enough to consider that sequence mod 100 which gives:
$$\begin{align}
b_0&\equiv 4\\
b_1&\equiv 14\\
b_2&\equiv 94\\
b_3&\equiv 34\\
b_4&\equiv 54\\
b_5&\equiv 14\\
\end{align}$$
Thus, $b_n\equiv b_{n \operatorname{mod} 4}$ for any $n\geqslant 1$ provided we use the remainders $\{1,2,3,4\}$ mod 4:
$$b_{2020}\equiv b_4 \equiv 54 \mod 100$$